# how do I remove "open with pdf-xchange" in the right click menu?

Tags: wine, pdf, winetricks

I've installed pdf-xchange using wine and found it buggy.

Then I try to uninstall it, however it is not shown in wine-uninstall.

So I went to ~/.wine/folder and delete it. But when I right click a pdf file, there is an option "open with pdf-xchange", so how do I remove that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wine works by storing a 'wineprefix' on the filesystem, by default `~/.wine`. This contains a virtual window drive for the program being run under Wine - but when you install a program under wine it also adds files to other locations so it works properly with the linux system (so just deleting the wineprefix is not always enough):

- `~/.local/share/appllictions` - this contains .desktop files, which act as launchers in the dash/menu etc.
- `~/.local/share/icons` - icons for the program
- `~/.local/share/mime` - mimetypes for files - a mimetype is probably in here saying that PDFxchange can opens PDFs etc.
- Some additional stuff -  e.g. `~/.config/menus/applications-merged`, `~/.cache/fontconfig`, `/.local/share/desktop-directories` etc. This will probably vary with the program that is installed.

So to remove it, removing the relevant 'pdf-xchange' and `wine*` files/folders in `~/.local/share/applications` should be enough *(note other programs use the above file and folders, so don't randomly delete everything)* - then run `update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications/` and restart the desktop/file manager to make the changes.